# Java how to read files recursive

Tags: java

I want to read **all files **recursive**** inside a given path and show the path and Byte size in the output of every single File.

Comment: Little hint: If you wanna check whether the file changed, do not use MD5 oder SHA etc. Use checksums like Adler32. Hashing algorithms like MD5, SHA-x are a lot slower, slower that the HDD you're reading from.

Comment: You can create a method which gets the file path as input. Next, for each file from a list (or in an infinite while loop if you want to run in console) you can send it to this method and get the md5

Comment: https://stackabuse.com/java-list-files-in-a-directory/

Comment: [Walking the File Tree](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/walk.html) (part of Oracle's Java tutorials).

Answer (score 0):

```
public class ReadFilesInPathRecursion {

public void listFiles (String startDir) {
    File dir = new File(startDir);
    File[] files = dir.listFiles();
    
    if (files!=null && files.length >= 0) {
        for(File file : files) {
            
            if(file.isDirectory()) {
                listFiles(file.getAbsolutePath()); // Recursion (absolute)
            } else {
                System.out.println(file.getName() + " (size in bytes: " + file.length() + ") " + "(path: " + file.getAbsoluteFile() + ")");
            }
            
        }
    }
    
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    ReadFilesInPathRecursion test = new ReadFilesInPathRecursion();
    String startDir = sc.next();
    test.listFiles(startDir);
    }
```